# Failing to open spreadsheet

Tags: openpyxl

I am currently parsing multiple spread sheets and running into problems opening a few of them. The error that is produced directs me to the file "Cell\text.py" at the line that joins the snippets together in the content property.

```
workBook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath, True)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.3.1-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 191, in load_workbook

shared_strings = read_string_table(archive.read(strings_path))

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.3.1-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\reader\strings.py", line 21, in read_string_table

text = Text.from_tree(node).content

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.3.1-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\cell\text.py", line 182, in content

return "".join(snippets)

TypeError: sequence item 3: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

If I alter the code to have a check around the appending of the blocks in the formatted section as follows:

```
for block in self.formatted:
        if(block.t is not None):                
            snippets.append(block.t)
```

It works fine, I was just wondering if there is some obvious problem with the excel sheet that I don't understand that someone could shed light on. I haven't rooted around the code for openpyxl so I am not sure what determines the contents of "self.formatted" but, My guess is that it is something caused by the merged cells in that area of the spread sheet.

**EDIT**

After reading your comments I dived a little deeper to see if there is any data I could share with you. I updated the Content property("Cell/Text.py") to output the data it was trying to join and searched the "sharedStrings.xml" for the xml data. The printed data was:

```
 ['“Replaced Data”', None]
```

After taking a look in the sharedStrings file the xml that contains this data is:

```
<si>
  <r>
    <t>“Replaced Data”</t>
  </r>
  <r>
    <rPr>
      <sz val="11"/>
      <color rgb="FF008080"/>
      <rFont val="Calibri"/>
      <family val="2"/>
      <scheme val="minor"/>
    </rPr>
  <t/>
  </r>
</si>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with merged cells but with the way text has been stored. Could you submit a bug report with a test file?

Comment: I can't submit the files that I am working with, I am sorry I can't be of more use.

Comment: Not even the sharedStrings.xml part of the archive? This contains both formatted and unformatted text which are merged to unformatted blocks. The text itself is totally unimportant but the form of the file is important. So if you have names in the text that you can't reveal the s/stepehen/blahblahblah. Alternatively, send me the file via pm.

Comment: I have added more information to the question if this helps. From a glance it seems there is an empty <\t> could this be the issue ?

Comment: Yeah, that </t> looks a problem. Can you submit a bug report with that snippet?

Comment: Thank you for you help, I will look into creating a bug report.

Comment: @Stephen can you post a link to the bug report?   Did you find any sort of workaround by way of reformatting the workbook?

Comment: @CharlieClark, I'm having this same problem in openpyxl version 2.3.2, which pip tells me is the latest version.  Is there a newer version with this issue fixed?

Comment: @CAB this is fixed in the 2.3 branch so you should be able to work with a checkout.

Comment: For anyone that is interested the following is the bug report. [link](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/565/failing-to-parse-formatting)